# How to add sections to the GridView

Tags: qt, qml

I have code which position images like grid using `GridView`. I need the same the same look only using `ListView`. Why i need this? Because `ListView` have `section` what doesn't have GridView. I want add images to section. Key for section will be date of image.

Here is how it looks now with GridView

[image: GridView images]

It should look the same with ListView but i don't know how to do this.
Her my code.

```
 Page
 {
    id: page
    JsonListModel
    {
        id: jsonModel
        source: page.jsonData
        keyField: "id"
    }
    GridView
    {
        id: view

        anchors.topMargin: dp(5)
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth:(parent.width/3)
        cellHeight: cellWidth
        model: jsonModel
        clip: true
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.OvershootBounds // for flicking
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem // to stop at begin of item


        delegate: Item
        {
            id: photo

            property var view: GridView.view
            property var isCurrent: GridView.isCurrentItem

            height: view.cellHeight
            width: view.cellWidth

            AppImage
            {
                id: appImage
                anchors
                {
                    rightMargin:
                    {
                        (index+1)%3 === 0 ? 0 : 3
                    }
                    bottomMargin: dp(20)
                    fill: parent
                }
                source: model.img_url
            }

            Text
            {
                anchors
                {
                    horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    top: appImage.bottom
                    topMargin: dp(2)
                    bottomMargin: dp(3)
                }
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                text: "%1%2".arg(model.text).arg(isCurrent ? " *" : "")
                font.pointSize: sp(9)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how it should look how it should look

[image]

Comment: Could you show an image of what you want to get (I mean with *the section* you want)?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes sure i added picture.

Comment: I guess the question should be _How to add sections to the GridView_, otherwise it sounds like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @folibis changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess that there is no ready solution that matches your needs. `GridView` has no section and `LisView` has no columns. I can suggest my own pseudo solution, a kind of workaround. We can create a grid and in this grid we can create sections. Since `GridView` has no `columnSpan` property I guess the `GridLayout` can be use instead.

So, this is the "view" item:

**GridSection.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Flickable {
    id: root
    property int columns: 1
    property ListModel model: ListModel {}
    property Component itemDelegate: Item {}
    property Component sectionDelegate: Item {}
    contentHeight: layout.height
    contentWidth: layout.width
    GridLayout {
        id: layout
        columns: 3
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var lastSection = "";
            for(var i = 0;i < root.model.count;i ++)
            {
                var element = root.model.get(i);
                if(element.section !== lastSection)
                    root.sectionDelegate.createObject(layout, { "name": element.section, "Layout.columnSpan": root.columns });

                root.itemDelegate.createObject(layout, { "name": element.name });
                lastSection = element.section;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage:

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    GridSection {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 3
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { name: "element1"; section: "section1" }
            ListElement { name: "element2"; section: "section1" }
            ListElement { name: "element3"; section: "section1" }
            ListElement { name: "element4"; section: "section2" }
            ListElement { name: "element5"; section: "section2" }
            ListElement { name: "element6"; section: "section3" }
            ListElement { name: "element7"; section: "section3" }
            ListElement { name: "element8"; section: "section3" }
            ListElement { name: "element9"; section: "section3" }
        }
        itemDelegate: Rectangle {
            property string name
            color: "greenyellow"
            width: 100
            height: 50
            Text {
                text: name
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
        sectionDelegate: Rectangle {
            property string name
            width: 300
            height: 20
            color: "orange"
            Text {
                text: name
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since we can't create dynamic properties in QML, we must first create static properties(`property string name`) in the delegates. But you can do the same in C++ using [setProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) without defining the static ones.

Comment: What if my model isn't static, but a list model derived from ```QAbstractItemModel``` in C++. How could I dynamic create the delegate components in QML (upon model rest, or element addition/deletion in the model)? ```Component.onCompleted``` wouldn't work because at that moment the model is still empty.

Comment: Also, does ```Flickable``` make sense here? Isn't it just an ```Item```?